# Merging two eloquent queries into one result

Tags: laravel, eloquent, controller

I have two tables in my db.
Table Permit

| ID | Permit_type | Max_allowed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Full | 24 |
| 2 | Half | 12 |
| 3 | Quarter | 6 |

Table Entry

| **ID** | User_ID | User_Name | Permit_type | Duration | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | John Smith | Full | 6 | Approved | 2023-12-08 |
| 2 | 2 | Adam West | Full | 8 | Approved | 2023-12-08 |
| 3 | 1 | John Smith | Full | 2 | Pending | 2023-12-08 |
| 4 | 1 | John Smith | Half | 2 | Approved | 2023-12-09 |
| 5 | 1 | John Smith | Quarter | 1 | Approved | 2023-12-07 |
| 6 | 2 | Adam West | Full | 3 | Approved | 2023-12-08 |
| 7 | 1 | John Smith | Full | 2 | Approved | 2023-12-08 |
| 8 | 1 | Adam West | Half | 2 | Approved | 2023-12-09 |
| 9 | 1 | John Smith | Quarter | 1 | Approved | 2023-12-07 |

I want to view the Entry details for each individual where the status is approved.

For : John Smith

| Permit_Type | Max_allowed | Sum(Duration) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Full | 24 | 8 |
| Half | 12 | 2 |
| Quarter | 6 | 2 |

For : Adam West

| Permit_Type | Max_allowed | Sum(Duration) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Full | 24 | 11 |
| Half | 12 | 2 |
| Quarter | 6 | 0 |

routes:

```
Route::get('/entry_details', [EntryController::class, 'get_entry_details']);
```

EntryController:

```
    public function get_entry_details(){

    $p1 = DB::table('Permit')->select('permit_type', 'max_allowed')->get();
    $p2 =DB::table('Entry')->where([['status', '=', 'Approved'],['user_id','=',1]])->select(DB::raw('SUM(duration) as duration'))->groupBy('permit_type')->get();

    $collection = collect($p1);
    $merged= $collection->merge($p2);
    $result = $merged->all();

    return view('/entry_details',$result);
    }
```

entry_details.blade.php

```
    <tr>
     <th>Permit Type</th>
     <th>Max Allowed</th>
     <th>Total Duration</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($result as $data)
    <tr>
     <td>{{$data->permit_type}} </td>
     <td>{{$data-max_allowed}} </td>
     <td>{{$data->duration}} </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Error:

```
Undefined variable $result
Error on line: **@foreach($result as $data)**
```

dd($result);
[dd($result) looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnkNd.png)

I don't know what I did wrong

Comment: return view('entry_details', compact('result'));

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the query. You are not passing your variable in view correctly.

To pass a variable to a view, you can use the following syntax:

```
return view('/entry_details',[ 'result' => $result]);
```

or

```
return view('/entry_details',compact('result'));
```

Comment: Because in your array, some of the elements don't have a parameter permit_type. you will get the same error for duration also. so use it if you want to show blank cells that use null safety while accessing those parameters. Instead of ``{{$data->permit_type}} `` this write like this ``{{$data->permit_type ?? ''}} `` for all parameters.

Comment: I did try that but now the table is displaying the data incorrectly; the permit type and max allowed columns are correct but the total duration is displaying on new rows.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are merging the two tables like this? Just join the two tables, will give you just one query and then you loop it over it in your blade.
BTW you are passing the result variable into view not correctly.
Change your code to this.

```
public function get_entry_details()
{
    $result = DB::table('Permit')
        ->leftJoin('Entry', function ($join) {
            $join->on('Permit.permit_type', '=', 'Entry.permit_type')
                ->where('Entry.status', 'Approved')
                ->where('Entry.user_id', auth()->id());
        })
        ->select('Permit.permit_type', 'Permit.max_allowed', DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(Entry.duration), 0) as duration'))
        ->groupBy('Permit.permit_type', 'Permit.max_allowed')
        ->get();



    return view('entry_details', compact('result'));
}
```

And then in the blade **entry_details** loop over it like this

```
<tr>
    <th>Permit Type</th>
    <th>Max Allowed</th>
    <th>Total Duration</th>
</tr>
@foreach($result as $data)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$data->permit_type}}</td>
        <td>{{$data->max_allowed}}</td>
        <td>{{$data->duration}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is working but this is showing only displaying the results that have a sum value. For instance if the user has no entry for a certain permit type then the duration should return 0.

Comment: aaha okay, i get it now let me update it. it will the other way around, joining permit to entry basically, check it now

Comment: Thanks for the update but I'm having issues with getting the user id dynamically.
I'm getting the logged user id by declaring the variable $user_id=Auth::user()->id;
But while using the variable in ->where('Entry.user_id', '=', $user_id); it is throwing error undefined variable.

Comment: aah okay so you want the authenticated user data ? just write the auth()->id() in place of 1 in user_id column, I have update it

Comment: Thank you for the updates it is working as I wanted.

Comment: Glad it worked, Kindly accept the answer.